# Obtener una conexion sql usando entityManager

Tags: java, sql, weblogic

Me gustaría saber si es posible poder establecer una conexión de BD tipo sql.connection haciendo uso de `entityManager`, es decir, yo necesito llamar a un `procedure` almacenado en la BD, normalmente realizando una conexión a la BD en donde previamente está definido el link, `user` y contraseña, obteniéndolo mediante un `getConexion` como la siguiente forma: `Conn = DriverManager.getConnection(connection, user, password);` y declarando una variable de tipo `CallableStatement nombreVariable = conn.prepareCall`... se puede ejecutar dicho `procedure` en la BD, pero debido a que el usuario contraseña y dirección se recibían del `persistence`, y dicha aplicación se migro a `WebLogic`, todo se maneja a través de un `datasource`, y las conexiones se gestionan a través de `entityManager` con **EclipseLink**, mi pregunta es cómo podría transformar de `entity` a `connection`, todo en pro a modificar la mayoría de los métodos ya realizados, algo así como:

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName = "rmsprd")
    public void setEm(EntityManager em) {
        this.em = em;

..........................

connection = this.getConexion();

CallableStatement statement = connection.prepareCall("call")
    }
```

Cabe destacar que usando el procedimiento anterior me arrojo una excepción

> "Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type:"

¿Alguien tiene alguna idea o sugerencia?

Con respecto a retorno NULL del entity manager

de esta manera obtengo mi persistenceUnit en mi entityManager

```
@PersistenceContext(unitName="rd")
private EntityManager em ;
@Override
public void setEm(EntityManager em) {
    this.em = em;
}
```

y aca mi metodo para obtener la conexion

```
 @Transactional
protected Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
    logger.info("contenido de Em en GetConnection"+em);
    if(em.unwrap(Connection.class) != null) {
        logger.info("entre a el if CONEXION ");
        logger.info("entityManager2"+this.em);
        return (Connection)this.em.unwrap(Connection.class);
    } else {
        logger.info("entre a el else CONEXION ");
        logger.info("contenido de Em en GetConnection"+em);
        Map datosConexion = em.getProperties();
        String url = (String)datosConexion.get("javax.persistence.jdbc.url");
        String user = (String)datosConexion.get("javax.persistence.jdbc.user");
        String password = (String)datosConexion.get("javax.persistence.jdbc.password");
        return DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
    }

}
```

a pesar de que el metodo esta de tipo transaccional aun me sigue retornando la excepcion, de hecho la variable EM ya viene null, a que se podra deber esto?

configuracion del persistence.xml

```
<persistence-unit name="rmsprd" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <jta-data-source>rmsprd</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties>
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Comment: `"Uncompilable source code"` indica que tienes un problema en tu código, no se puede compilar. Ni siquiera se puede ejecutar. Revisa bien dónde tienes este problema. Con el código provisto, no podemos ayudarte mucho.

Comment: Por si acaso, JPA 2.2 ya permite la ejecución de procedimientos almacenados.

Answer (score 1):

Si usas EclipseLink, y según la versión de JPA:

**JPA 2.0**

```
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    java.sql.Connection connection = entityManager.unwrap(java.sql.Connection.class); // unwraps the Connection class.

    ...
    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
```

**JPA 1.0**

```
entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
UnitOfWork unitOfWork = (UnitOfWork)((JpaEntityManager)entityManager.getDelegate()).getActiveSession();
unitOfWork.beginEarlyTransaction();
Accessor accessor = unitOfWork.getAccessor();
accessor.incrementCallCount(unitOfWork.getParent());
accessor.decrementCallCount();
java.sql.Connection connection = accessor.getConnection();
...
entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
```

Sacado de un [hilo de SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6707115/get-hold-of-a-jdbc-connection-object-from-a-stateless-bean), que a su vez referencia al [wiki de EclipseLink](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/EMAPI#Getting_a_JDBC_Connection_from_an_EntityManager).

Añadiendo a lo comentado por Luggi Mendoza, un ejemplo de la nueva manera de llamar a PLs, **JPA 2.1** en adelante:

```
StoredProcedureQuery query = this.em.createStoredProcedureQuery("nombreProcedimiento");
query.registerStoredProcedureParameter("paramEntrada1", Double.class, ParameterMode.IN);
query.registerStoredProcedureParameter("paramEntrada2", Double.class, ParameterMode.IN);
query.registerStoredProcedureParameter("paramSalida1", Double.class, ParameterMode.OUT);
query.setParameter("paramEntrada1", 1.23d);
query.setParameter("paramEntrada2", 4.56d);

query.execute();
Double sum = (Double) query.getOutputParameterValue("paramSalida1");
```

Comment: gracias por la pronta respuesta y he probado esas alternativas, haciendo uso del unWrap, me lanza el cannotFindsymbol  method unWrap,a pesar de compilar al desplegar y correr en weblogic captura ese error, con el UnitOfWork al instanciar "Accesor" no me reconoce el metodo getAccesor, por ultimo con StoreProcedureQuery, a pesar de importarlo, al usar el createStoredProcedure, no lo reconoce, a pesar de compilar en java 1.6...1.7...1.8, al correr la app me lanza esas excepciones, que creen ustedes que pueda ser?

Comment: Ese error es por la versión de Java. ¿Cómo compilas? ¿Usas maven? ¿Qué versión de Java soporta tu Weblogic?

Comment: ya resolví ese problema amigo, era que habian dos librerias con hacian uso de la clase entity manager y a la cual apuntaba era a la que no tenia integrados los metodos que solicitaba, aunque bien ya elimino esos errores y puedo compilar, cuando intento obtener la conexion de mi entityManager me manda null y usando otra que instancie "me manda java.lang.IllegalStateException: No transactional EntityManager available" en realidad no se que pueda estar pasando, si tienes alguna sugerencia, agradecido

Comment: Prueba añadiendo @Transactional al método

Comment: amigo pablo asi esta mi metodo y a pesar de eso aun retorna null, es como si el entity manager no captura las propiedades de la conexion, en la edicion de mi pregunta coloque el metodo que uso, a ver si ves que pudiera estar haciendo mal

Comment: ¿Cómo tienes definido el persistente.xml?En tu pregunta haces referencia a dos unitName diferentes, ¿es eso correcto?

Comment: si lo que pasa es que te pase el codigo que tenia de prueba fuera del proyecto, pero si es el mismo unit persistence del inicio, en la edicion colocare como lo tengo definido el persistence-unit